# How to get similar elements from two streams and collect the pairs thus formed without losing the order?

Tags: java, dictionary, filter, java-stream, reduce

For instance:
Inputs are infinite streams which are made available as finite lists for each pass of the map reduce:

```
 list 1:  List<String> : {"a1_5", "c1_91", "b1_43", "b1_76", "a1_68"}
 list 2:  List<String> : {"c2_3", "b2_19", "c2_29", "a2_45", "b2_53"}
```

My output should be an infinite stream made out of a List output instance:

```
List<String> : {"a1_5,a2_45", "c1_91,c2_3", "b1_43,b2_19", "b1_76,b2_53", "a1_68,a2_45"}
```

or the output could be:

```
List<String> : {"c1_91,c2_3", "b1_43,b2_19", "a1_5,a2_45", "b1_76,b2_53"}
```

Comment: Are you speaking about Java-8 Streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is about Java 8 Streams, it can be solved with quite sophisticated custom Spliterator like this:

```
public static <T,K,R> Stream<R> pairs(Stream<T> a, Stream<T> b, 
                 Function<T, K> keyExtractor, BiFunction<T, T, R> merger) {
    Map<K, Queue<T>> aMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<K, Queue<T>> bMap = new HashMap<>();
    Spliterator<T> aSpltr = a.spliterator();
    Spliterator<T> bSpltr = b.spliterator();

    Spliterator<R> res = new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<R>(Math.min(
            aSpltr.estimateSize(), bSpltr.estimateSize()), Spliterator.ORDERED) {
        T at, bt;
        boolean hasBuffered = false;
        R buf;

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super R> action) {
            if(hasBuffered) {
                hasBuffered = false;
                action.accept(buf);
                return true;
            }
            while(true) {
                if(!aSpltr.tryAdvance(t -> at = t) || !bSpltr.tryAdvance(t -> bt = t))
                    return false;
                K ak = keyExtractor.apply(at);
                K bk = keyExtractor.apply(bt);
                Queue<T> bq = bMap.get(ak);
                boolean found = false;
                if(bq != null) {
                    found = true;
                    action.accept(merger.apply(at, bq.poll()));
                    if(bq.isEmpty()) bMap.remove(ak);
                } else {
                    aMap.computeIfAbsent(ak, k -> new ArrayDeque<>()).add(at);
                }
                Queue<T> aq = aMap.get(bk);
                if(aq != null) {
                    if(found) {
                        hasBuffered = true;
                        buf = merger.apply(aq.poll(), bt);
                    } else {
                        found = true;
                        action.accept(merger.apply(aq.poll(), bt));
                    }
                    if(aq.isEmpty()) aMap.remove(bk);
                } else {
                    bMap.computeIfAbsent(bk, k -> new ArrayDeque<>()).add(bt);
                }
                if(found)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    };
    return StreamSupport.stream(res, a.isParallel() || b.isParallel())
              .onClose(a::close).onClose(b::close);
}
```

This method accepts two streams (possibly infinite), key extractor function (in your case first character need to be extracted) and merge function (how to combine two elements together; in your case join using `","`). Here's usage example:

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a1_5", "c1_91", "b1_43", "b1_76", "a1_68"); 
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("c2_3", "b2_19", "c2_29", "a2_45", "b2_53"); 
pairs(list1.stream(), list2.stream(), s -> s.charAt(0), (a, b) -> a+","+b)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
c1_91,c2_3
b1_43,b2_19
a1_5,a2_45
b1_76,b2_53
```

Alternative example with actually infinite streams: combine pairs of random numbers from two streams which differ only by last digit:

```
pairs(new Random().ints(0, 1000).boxed(), new Random().ints(0, 1000).boxed(),
        i -> i/10, (a, b) -> a+","+b)
    .limit(100)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that for infinite stream it's possible to have `OutOfMemoryError` if you have many unpaired elements in the streams.

Comment: This looks great. May you please suggest a book or an article or something that would help me nail this concept with more examples. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @aksinghdce, erm... I don't know. I've just read the official Stream API documentation (javadoc) and hundreds of StackOverflow questions. And wrote dozens of spliterators by myself.

Comment: @aksinghdce Maybe [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both List are the same size you could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("a1_5");
    list1.add("c1_91");
    list1.add("b1_43");
    list1.add("b1_76");
    list1.add("a1_68");

    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("c2_3");
    list2.add("b2_19");
    list2.add("c2_29");
    list2.add("a2_45");
    list2.add("b2_53");

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        result.add(list1.get(i) + "," + list2.get(i));
    }

    //Printing the results
    for (String a : result) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

If the lists may have different sizes I would control it with some basic code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("a1_5");
    list1.add("c1_91");
    list1.add("b1_43");
    list1.add("b1_76");
    list1.add("a1_68");
    //New instance
    list1.add("a2");

    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("c2_3");
    list2.add("b2_19");
    list2.add("c2_29");
    list2.add("a2_45");
    list2.add("b2_53");     

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    int aux = 0;
    if (list1.size() >= list2.size()) {
        aux = list1.size();
    } else {
        aux = list2.size();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < aux; i++) {
        if(i == list1.size()){
            result.add(null+","+list2.get(i));
        }else if(i == list2.size()){
            result.add(list1.get(i)+","+null);
        }else{
            result.add(list1.get(i)+","+list2.get(i));
        }           
    }

    //Printing the results
    for (String a : result) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed one core idea in the question. The output should have paired matching. That is, (a1_xx, a2_xx), (b1_xx, b2_xx). a1_xx can't be paired with b2_xx. Also, if some data that is missing in list1 to be paired with an existing data in list2, then list1 should wait for the new data to come in.

Comment: list1 doesn't have all the data. The output must contain tuples with first element from list1 and second from list2 that matches. I believe you understood the problem.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you talk about Java 8 Streams, the lists have the same length, each element can be paired in the way you described and you don't mind to use the additional lib Javaslang, it could be done this way (works for lists of different sizes though):

```
// functional way
static List<String> pairingFun(List<String> list1, List<String> list2,
                               BiPredicate<String, String> isPair) {
    return pairingFun(list1.size(), Stream.empty(), Stream.ofAll(list1), Stream.ofAll(list2).cycle(), isPair)
            .toJavaList();
}

// recursive helper function
static Stream<String> pairingFun(int size, Stream<String> acc, Stream<String> stream1, Stream<String> stream2,
                                 BiPredicate<String, String> isPair) {
    if (stream1.isEmpty()) {
        return acc;
    } else {
        String elem1 = stream1.head();
        Option<String> elem2 = stream2.take(size).find(that -> isPair.test(elem1, that));
        return pairingFun(size,
                elem2.map(elem -> acc.append(elem1 + "," + elem)).getOrElse(acc),
                stream1.tail(),
                elem2.isDefined() ? stream2.dropUntil(that -> isPair.test(elem1, that)).tail() : stream2,
                isPair);
    }
}
```

In the ideal case you would not convert forth and back between Java collections and Javaslang collections and only use Javaslang collections. This would reduce the boilerplate even more. However, I suspect most probably you are bound to the API of other 3rd party libs.

But beware, we use a recursive function above which may produce a stack overflow, if list1 contains too many elements. Therefore I would suggest to do it the good old imperative way:

```
// imperative way
static List<String> pairingImp(List<String> list1, List<String> list2,
                               BiPredicate<String, String> isPair) {
    int size = list1.size();
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(size);
    Stream<String> stream = Stream.ofAll(list2).cycle();
    for (String elem1 : list1) {
        Option<String> elem2 = stream.take(size).find(that -> isPair.test(elem1, that));
        if (elem2.isDefined()) {
            result.add(elem1 + "," + elem2.get());
            stream = stream.dropUntil(that -> isPair.test(elem1, that)).tail();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is a test:

```
import javaslang.collection.Stream;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;

// ...

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a1_5", "c1_91", "b1_43", "b1_76", "a1_68");
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("c2_3", "b2_19", "c2_29", "a2_45", "b2_53");

    BiPredicate<String, String> isPair = (s1, s2) -> s1.charAt(0) == s2.charAt(0);

    // [a1_5,a2_45, c1_91,c2_3, b1_43,b2_19, b1_76,b2_53, a1_68,a2_45]
    System.out.println(pairingFun(list1, list2, isPair));

    // [a1_5,a2_45, c1_91,c2_3, b1_43,b2_19, b1_76,b2_53, a1_68,a2_45]
    System.out.println(pairingImp(list1, list2, isPair));
}
```

Because we iterate list2 for each element of list1, we have quadratic runtime performance, i.e. O(n^2). This may be further improved by using a map to lookup pairing candidates. I think the fastest solution will perform in O(n * log n).

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Javaslang.

Comment: Seems that your solution will stuck in infinite loop if first stream contains unpaired element (completely absent in the second one) and the second stream is infinite. Not sure if this possible in OP scenario...

Comment: Yes you're right, it is assumed that pairs exist. What should be the output if the stream contains unpaired canditiates?
And: My version is not correct, I currently drop only one element of list2  after each pairing. I will correct that.

Comment: Tagir, it is relatively simple to catch the case where no pairing exisits. The streams are immutable, we can limit the current version of the cycled stream2 by the size of the original list1 because we know that then every element of the original list2 occurs. All operations are lazily evaluated, i.e. the limited stream2 is not necessarily iterated completely in the search of a pairing. However, we need one more if to check, if a pairing exsits for an element of list1. I will update the solution accordingly if you don't mind.

Comment: Aarrgh - my fix is not correct - I currently have no IDE at hands. Will fix it again...

Comment: Sorry, I did not expect that my comment would take so much of your time :-)

Comment: It is ok - it is fun! The current version works fine - also for the non-pairing-found case.

Answer (score 0):

This Channel class is my naive approach of solving the problem. I will be doing it more crisply using java 8 streams as suggested by @Daniel Dietrich and @Tagir Valeev.

The match function does the real work.

```
    class Channel{

private StringBuilder output_string_builder = null;

public static void main(String[] args){
           Channel ch1 = new Channel(list_channel1);
           Channel ch2 = new Channel(list_channel2);
           Integer count1 = new Integer(ch1.getQ().size());
           Integer count2 = new Integer(ch2.getQ().size());
           while((ch1.getQ().size()>0 && count1>0) 
                 && (ch2.getQ().size()>0 && count2>0))
           {
                 ch1.match(ch2, output_string_builder);
                 count1--;
                 count2--;
           }
     System.out.println(output_string_builder.toString());

}


private List<String> Rs;
private List<String> Gs;
private List<String> Bs;
private List<String> my_list;

public Channel(List<String> channel_list){
    Rs = new ArrayList<String>();
    Gs = new ArrayList<String>();
    Bs = new ArrayList<String>();
    my_list = channel_list;
    for(String str: channel_list){
        if(str.charAt(0) == 'R'){
            insertR(str);
        }
        if(str.charAt(0) == 'G'){
            insertG(str);
        }
        if(str.charAt(0) == 'B'){
            insertB(str);
        }
    }
}

public List<String> getQ(){
    return my_list;
}

public void match(Channel ch, StringBuilder output){

    if(getQ().size() < 1 || ch.getQ().size() < 1){
        return;
    }

        String str = ch.getQ().get(0);
        if(str.charAt(0) == 'R' && hasR()){
            //self updated
            String my_val = this.getR();
            getQ().remove(my_val);

            //remote channel's data updated
            ch.getQ().remove(str);
            ch.getR();

            //need to do placing of string 1 before 2
            if(str.charAt(1) == '1'){
                output.append(str + "," + my_val + " ");
            }
            else{
                output.append(my_val + "," + str + " ");
            }



        }
        if(str.charAt(0) == 'G' && hasG()){
            //self updated
            String my_val = this.getG();
            getQ().remove(my_val);

            //remote channel's data updated
            ch.getQ().remove(str);
            ch.getG();

            //need to do placing of string 1 before 2
            if(str.charAt(1) == '1'){
                output.append(str + "," + my_val + " ");
            }
            else{
                output.append(my_val + "," + str + " ");
            }



        }
        if(str.charAt(0) == 'B' && hasB()){
            //self updated
            String my_val = this.getB();
            getQ().remove(my_val);

            //remote channel's data updated
            ch.getQ().remove(str);
            ch.getB();

            //need to do placing of string 1 before 2
            if(str.charAt(1) == '1'){
                output.append(str + "," + my_val + " ");
            }
            else{
                output.append(my_val + "," + str + " ");
            }



        }

}

private void insertR(String _string){
    Rs.add(_string);
}
private void insertG(String _string){
    Gs.add(_string);
}
private void insertB(String _string){
    Bs.add(_string);
}

public boolean hasR(){
    if(Rs.size() > 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean hasG(){
    if(Gs.size() > 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean hasB(){
    if(Bs.size() > 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public String getR(){
    if(hasR()){
        return Rs.remove(0);
    }
    return null;

}
public String getG(){
    if(hasG()){
    return Gs.remove(0);
    }
    return null;
}

public String getB(){
    if(hasB()){
    return Bs.remove(0);
    }
    return null;
}


}
```

The output is tested with infinite stream of data coming in through SocketChannel that are read into two Lists.